# type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement authentication for login and getting below error :

```
A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.
```

Code :

```
this.isLoggedIn = false;

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean>{
    let url: string = state.url;
    return this.checkLogin(url);
}

checkLogin(url: string): Observable<boolean> {

    this.authService.isUserLoggedIn()
        .map(
           data => {
        // getting true or false as  loggedIn value
            this.isLoggedIn = data.loggedIn;


            if (this.isLoggedIn) {       
              return true;
            }

            // Redirect on home page with login popup.
            this.router.navigate(['/']);

            return false;

         });
}
```

couldn't figure out whats the problem is.

Comment: Well, your checkLogin() method doesn't return anything, as the error says. `return this.authService.isUserLoggedIn()...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @JBNizet  Thank you for point out missing part.

Comment: @JBNizet one more thing, how can we access variable isLoggedIn into component ?

Comment: What you posted is a CanActivate guard. Its use is to prevent the router from navigating to a route if the user is not logged in. So, from the component of that route, you don't need to check if the user is logged in: the router wouldn't let you access the route if not logged in.

Comment: Yes thats fine but i want to perform some activity based on user is logged in or not. means, want to display log in (if user is not logged in) or display my account (in case of user is logged in) from the common component like header.

Comment: Well, just do what you're doing here: inject the authService, call isUserLoggedIn(), and subscribe to the observable.

Comment: ok, i have to  trigger http request to check user is logged in or not. As i have multiple component in which i want to check user is logged in or not then i need to trigger multiple http request to check the same thing. As we have already checked this in canActivate guard, can't we do something from that result ?

Comment: Cache the result of the first call in the service, using a Promise for example.